# discrete Cepstrum: can you help me understand it?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, cepstral-analysis, envelope

Since months I am working on a spectral envelope estimation algorithm. I even devised an innovative one (90% done) but I first wanted to have a complete panorama of the present art. I pretty understood most of the published methods and their limitations, including cepstral smoothing, lpc and true envelope. Unfortunately I cannot understand the Discrete Cepstrum method even minimally. I am an experienced dsp coder but not a math guru, I tried to study all web pages and publications explaining it but they are using too many complex formulas and obscure math concepts and my mind gets lost. But since I am not stupid, if someone would explain it to me in layman terms I would surely understand its principle. Can somebody help or offer a link where the Discrete Cepstrum is explained with understandable words ?

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question with the specific bits you don't understand? That way we can answer more directly.

Comment: Call me stupid but I don't get any single bit of the way it is described, simply said :(